# [Postfix]: check_sender_access: How to catch envelope FROM with brackets?

Tags: postfix

### Overall goal:

Block specific emails with have "a name" included in their FROM envelope. Example: `John <john@example.com>`

### Current situation:

I have successfully configured the `main.cf` of **Postfix** to utilize `check_sender_access` in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

I have created my own `sender_access` file, used postmap on it, so it generates sender_access.db, which is used then by `main.cf`.

My sender_access file looks like this:

```
john@example.com REJECT
support@example.com REJECT
```

This configuration **does works** as intended and rejects the email when somebody sends an inbound email with "clear" FROM envelope (Example: `FROM: support@example.com`):

[image]

This configuration **does not work** and reject the email when the sender has set a "name" which appears in the FROM envelope (Example: `FROM: John <john@example.com>` or `FROM: Support <support@example.com>`):

[image]

The configuration "does not catch" the email address either when the "name" is the same as the email address (some default behavior in some MTA /mail transfer agents/):

[image]

### What I have tried:

I have tried a sender_access file with the following formatting:

```
john@example.com REJECT
John <john@example.com> REJECT
"John <john@example.com>" REJECT
John REJECT
<john@example.com> REJECT
"john@example.com" REJECT
john@ REJECT
```

None of these have practically worked. The only thing which works is if I reject the entire domain:

```
example.com REJECT
```

### My question:

I have been searching for two days now, tried many articles and finally decided to ask here. Does Postfix support blocking of senders with FROM in the format `John <john@example.com>`?

Do I need to try some regex (interestingly, I didn't found any - one would think this is something commonsense?).

P.S: Perhaps something which always "catches" the email address inside the brackets in bold:

> John **<john@example.com>**

Thank you!

Comment: Your terminology is confused. You are not actually talking about the ‘envelope from’. The ‘envelope from’ would be the [MAIL FROM command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.2) which does not allow a name at all, *only* a mailbox in angle brackets. The envelope is usually not visible in a web interface.

Comment: Perhaps a more helpful comment, if you are asking about the `From:` header then have a look at the manual page *header_checks*(5) (`man 5 header_checks`), it might just be what you’re looking for. Or ask on the Postfix mailing list.

Comment: ^--- Your suggestions are all wrong. But thanks anyway, E for Effort. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

I solved this problem by using regular expressions (regexp) checks.

---

**main.cf**

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

**sender_access**

```
# Exact match: john@example.com
/^john@example\.com$/ REJECT

# Advanced match: John <john@example.com>
/john@example\.com/ REJECT
```

**Note:** Please be aware if you use only `/john@example.com/` without terminating with `\` the `.` character, then it will match all characters in that position except linebreaks (Example: `john@example$.com` , `john@example!.com`, etc.)

---

### Testing

You can test your `sender_access` via with the command:

```
postmap -q "John <john@example.com" regexp:sender_access
```

Do not forget to use the following commands in order to make sure your changes take effect:

```
postmap sender_access
service postfix restart
```

---

### Additional notes:

**1.** If you add a new rule within the sender_access file, doing only a `postmap sender_access` seems to be enough.

**2.** Sometimes even though the email appears in the frontend to come from `John <john@example.com` it is actually emailed from an address like `<12323323487210921@mail.example.com>`. This is especially through if the sender uses a service such as Amazon SES.

In this case you must block the actual domain (Example in `sender_access`: `/^john@example\.com$/ REJECT`). You can see the real address in your Postfix logs:

```
vim /var/log/mail.log
```

Comment: Isn't this supposed to go under `smtpd_sender_restrictions` rather than `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` ?